# Xcode multiple Storyboards

Tags: ios, xcode

Currently I have an iOS project that has one Storyboard with a lot of views. The problem is that loading the project takes too long. Is there any way I can divide my project into multiple storyboards? How would I connect the Storyboards (getting from a view of one storyboard to the view of another Storyboard)?

thanks

Comment: Yes, you can divide your storyboard into multiple short sizes storyboard. Here is a useful link - http://www.newventuresoftware.com/blog/organizing-xcode-projects-using-multiple-storyboards/

Comment: Yes, you can split viewcontroller in different storyboards - [Working with multiple storyboards](http://www.smikeapps.com/working-with-multiple-storyboards/)

Answer (score 2):

Yes , You can use multiple storyboard in a project, Suppose you have ABC.Storyboard and XYZ.Storyboard and Now you want to load XYZ.Storyboard viewcontroller from ABC.Storyboard viewcontroller -

**Objective c**

```
UIStoryboard *sbXYZ = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"XYZ" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [sbXYZ instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewController"];
vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

**Swift**

```
let sbXYZ = UIStoryboard(name: "XYZ", bundle: nil)
let vc = sbXYZ.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myViewController") as! UIViewController
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Would you mind translating the code to Swift? I have no knowledge whatsoever in Objective C:/

Comment: I tried it, but still it doesn't really work. Is there anything I have to create or configure for the other storyboard? Currently, I created a new storyboard and a new corresponding view controller ViewController1, but XCode is unable to find it when I run it.

Comment: did you provide viewcontroller  identifier name from storyboard

Comment: yes. In fact, the error ist: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x7ff4a1d25820>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'ViewController1''

Comment: however, I do have a view controller that is clearly identified with ViewController1

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode 7 you can now link between storyboards.
Here is a link to the [Apple doc](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#/dev66c5f17da).

Or search for 
Adding a Reference to Another Storyboard

This says

1. Open the storyboard to contain the reference in the interface builder.
2. Open the utilities area for the workspace window
3. Select the Object library from the utilities area
4. Drag the Storyboard Reference object from the library onto the canvas
5. Configure the attributes of the storyboard reference.

A storyboard reference has three attributes:

Storyboard is the name of the referenced .storyboard file.
Referenced ID is Storyboard ID of the referenced scene.
Bundle is the bundle containing the referenced storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

You won't solve the issue simply by splitting the storyboard because Xcode still has to compress the binary and load it.

I would suggest doing either:

1) simplify your coding so that any needless coding doesn't bog the load time down

If your code is spot on

2) it's most likely your imported images are not compressed correctly. Try to reduce their size as much as you can without compromising quality. This is most likely why everything's taking so long to load.

Google 'how to manage images for Xcode'

Comment: I guess he is talking about loading the 'project' and not the binary or app.

Comment: Yes sorry I meant loading the project

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have multiple storyboards
I currently have this code, hope this will help you.. This is for objective C.. for swift, its already posted above by @SantuC.. It's up to you how to configure and support different orientations..

```
- (UIStoryboard *)activeStoryBoard
{
        BOOL isIPhone5 = ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568);

        BOOL isIPhone = ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom]   == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone);

        BOOL isIPad = ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom]   == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad);

        UIStoryboard *storyboard;

        if (isIPhone) {
            storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone-3.5in" bundle:nil];
        }

        if (isIPhone5) {
            storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone-4in" bundle:nil];
        }

        if (isIPad) {
            storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPad" bundle:nil];
        }

        return storyboard;
    }
```

Hope i've help you, Happy coding.. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Just suggest something here, if it's really taking too long to load. This will be a failure project from my perspectives. If for organizing, you can separate it into single xib file. However, that will be the same loading time as you use multiple storyboards.

The only way to solve this problem is coding programmatically.